# java getting error 403 on calling web service

Tags: java

I am newbie to java.I am calling webservice and getting error 403 through java,but when i call through curl it's working.here is my code for curl

```
$ curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" \
       -X GET  https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/categories/jewelry?api_key={api_key}
```

Here is Java Code:

```
try {

        URL url = new URL("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/active?api_key={api_key}");
        System.out.println(url.toString());
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        //conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");  

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }
```

Comment: Have you tried `HttpsURLConnection` instead?

Comment: I tried HttpsURLConnection,but its returning same 403 error

Comment: Have the same problem, were you guys able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

403 means Forbidden Action.

My guess is, authentication is required to use that web service, which you aren't providing in your code.

Comment: then why with `curl` the request gets proper response

Comment: But we are providing api key for authentication

Answer (score 0):

A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server can be reached and understood the request, but refuses to take any further action. **Status code 403 responses are the result of the web server being configured to deny access, for some reason, to the requested resource by the client.**  Read the api and make sure that you are not missing anything while making your request .I tried the `POST` also with `HttpsURLConnection` but not working